# Trying to better understand NodeJS with Redis and using a background task

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm trying to test a node server locally for something I eventually want to deploy on DigitalOcean (which is a whole other story). I have successfully setup a local node server with rest endpoints and a self signed cert for the time being. My issue is I want to store data that my user's can retrieve by hitting a rest endpoint. My current thought is that I would have some sort of background task running on the server that is constantly getting new data, so that when some of the more popular queries come through, I have the newest data for them, sanitized and ready to go.

My problem is I can't understand how I am suppose to have a background function running that will call itself over and over again without eventually causing a memory problem. I was looking at Bull or Kue, but I am not sure if those are suitable for my specific needs. I've also never dealt with NoSQL databases before, so Redis is fairly new to me to. Any suggestions or pointers? I'm a little overwhelmed and not sure where to go from here even though I have a general idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need a background running task. If your rest service has an endpoint that resolve a query that should be enough right? you would return the result for that query, keeping the database updated is another problem, it's not supposed to be handled by that endpoint I guess

Comment: @YerkoPalma I set up my server to sanitize the data for me before it goes to the user. This is because otherwise, the endpoint the data actually originates from (which is on another server I don't manage) comes in full XML and then my app would have to sort and sanitize it (which I don't want). So I want to keep getting the data on my server's time, not my user's.

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind.  If you're using the "hiredis" package you can attain 200k queries / sec on a modern quad core.  It's conceivable you could just retrieve the freshest data every time.

The other option involves updating application memory at startup and again at intervals.  A recursive call to a function with:

```js
function updateValuesFromRedis(seconds) {
  return redishmgetAsyc('keyhash')
    .then(function(values) {
      return saveValues(values);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Updating...');
        updateValuesFromRedis(seconds);
      }, 1000 * seconds)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error updating values from Redis!', error);
    });
}

(function schedule() {
  updateValuesFromRedis(60);
})();
```

Comment: Cool, and that schedule function would go in the call that initiates my node server?

Also, why hiredis as oppose to ioredis or some other redis client for node?